# How to discover devices other subnet

Tags: networking, arp

Printers like some thermal I have tried Bixolon and samsung laser printer ,even mikrotik router have a tool where they discover the device via its mac address.No matter what the ip is. And they discover it fast within seconds. How is this done ? So in case you lost the printer or router from bad configuration you can find them with this tool. How can I do the same ? All arp scans here seem to look a subnet.
I havent got any answer for this only "these devices want to be discovered" but doesnt answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the term "multicast".

Using e.g. SLP (Service Location Protocol) multicast discovery you can possibly find printers also in remote subnets. For example HP Jetdirect specific multicast address: 224.0.1.60

Other methods can be SNMP broadcast queries or plain IP range discovery (specific network scan).

Comment: so they have an address that they know ?

Comment: The example 224.0.1.60 looks like a pretty specific address to me.

Comment: I did some test and it seems to have to do with broadcast ip range. Thank you for helping. Question closed by ret*